# How can I downgrade to php4 to run ionCube

Tags: php, encoding, ioncube

The file **/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/mysql.php** was encoded by the **ionCube** Encoder for PHP 4 and cannot run under PHP 5.5.

Please ask the provider of the script to provide a version encoded with the ionCube Encoder for either PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5. in Unknown on line 0.

Is there a way or a trick to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try an ionCube decoder, but the whole idea behind encoding it is so you cannot get at the sources. It's probably not allowed by your provider to hack their encoded PHP code. So, no, there's no trick other than contacting your provider.

Comment: The application is running on a root server, this means that i have the possibility to customize the php if i know what to do

Comment: Is the MySQL database server running on the same computer and also under your control? If not, can you run one?

Comment: Well, then it is easy, you don't need the encoded `mysql.php` file. Just use your own unencoded version. It would have helped if you had said, in your question, where the file came from, and what you use it for. I assumed you needed it to access the database server, which turns out not to be the case.